# Ansible: 'groups' variable is undefined

Tags: ansible

I'm getting a strange error when trying to apply a role: apparently 'groups' (the builtin variable) is undefined. I've tested on a play in the same playbook and the variable works. Any ideas?

```yaml
- name: wtf?
  gather_facts: True
  hosts: tag_Name_Consul_server
  sudo: True
  user: username
  tasks:
    - name: thing
      debug: msg="-join {{ groups['tag_consul_server'][0] }}"

- name: blah
  gather_facts: True
  hosts: tag_Name_Consul_server
  sudo: True
  user: username
  vars:
    consul_command: "-join {{ groups['tag_consul_server'][0] }}"
  roles:
    - consul_server
```

The first play works fine, the second fails with:

> ERROR! the field 'vars' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'groups' is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was a bug, and has been patched in the latest version of Ansible!

Answer (score 0):

Built-in variables are prefixed by 'ansible_'. So you should use:

```
consul_command: "-join {{ ansible_groups['tag_consul_server'][0] }}"
```

UPDATE
This is not your solution, i'm confusion two things here. The group membership isn't parsed yet when loading playbook static vars. This apparently happens after loading the vars.